# Why do I get a 404 after I login to springs default login page?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am getting a 404 after I loggin in a very simple Spring Boot Application. It happen's since I added the password encoder stuff into my configureAuth method. Can someone help me?

Here ist my security configuration code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configureAuth(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()).dataSource(dataSource).withDefaultSchema()
            .withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin123")).roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable()
            .headers().frameOptions().disable();
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
}
```

There is no exception or other error. A simple whitelabel error page with 404 is showing up.

EDIT: The login form is coming up, but I think there is something wrong with the authentication.

Thank you,
Christian

Comment: Ok. My fault. It all works fine. I am still missing the page after a successfull login...

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure requests to the login form I believe. [Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/form.html).

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login");
}
```

From what it looks like, it's important to specify the `.loginPage`. I'm using the following config for my project.

```
    http.
    .authorizeRequests().antMathcers("/login-page", "/login", "/successful-login", "/error-login").anonymous().and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login-page") 
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/successful-login")
    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
    .failureUrl("/error-login")
        .permitAll()
```

The `.loginProcessingUrl` is I believe the URL to handle the login POST request.

I'm also using the [`@EnableWebSecurity`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableWebSecurity.html) annotation on my SecurityConfig class,

Comment: Thanks for your help! I changed the code to .loginPage(...) as you suggested and after I got an error I changed it back again and now it works. LOL... However... wait... now it' s not working again!

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm the only one that faces this issue but sometimes when logging in, the request doesn't register properly and I get an error like `Request Method POST Not supported`, it happens every once in a while but for the most part my config works fine.

Comment: Is that your entire `SecurityConfiguration` class that you've posted?

Comment: But thanks a lot! I found my problem... (see comment above)

Comment: I've updated my answer, I think it may be to do with the fact that you didn't have the `authorizeRequests` to the page you're trying to redirect to or process.

Answer (score 0):

My case...

> 1. It worked properly

antMatchers("/admin/**")

> 2. It was failed after I changed like this

antMatchers("/admin/xxx", "/admin/yyyy", "/admin/zzz")

> 3. Solution is to add the loginProc URL like this

antMatchers("/admin/xxx", "/admin/yyyy", "/admin/zzz", "/admin/loginProc")